# WPF & MVVM : Update an image field without breaking the pattern

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm

I'm currently learning how to write a WPF application using the MVVM pattern. I'm writing a little contact manager application, so my app displays a Listbox bound to my View Model, and a set of fields bound to ListBox.SelectedItem. One of these fields is the contact's photo.

I'd like to change the photo in the edit part using OpenFileDialog, so the Listbox item would be updated, as it is for all of the other fields.

I first tried to update the source property of the Image control, but doing this, I lose the Binding... 
Then I wrote an handler on Button_Click to update the Contact.Photo property (its type is byte[]), and it works. But instead of binding from the "update control" to the view model, binding is from the VM to the control, as if the data came from the DB.

(In the code, LoadPhoto returns a byte[])

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        (listbox.SelectedItem as ContactManager.ViewModel.Contact).Photo = 
                LoadPhoto(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

I wonder if it doesn't break the MVVM pattern... I'm not sure of what could be made in the View... Is it the right way to update the Contact object ? Does anyone have a better solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into binding your button to a Command Binding instead of the click event.
You can find implementations of DelegateCommand using Google.
Next you can expose a ImageSource from your ViewModel that you can bind to your Image from your XAML.

I've included some code fragments to get you started.

Once you get past the basics take a look at MVVM Frameworks, like [Cinch](http://cinch.codeplex.com/), you'll find a way to handle OpenFileDialog using the [Services Interfaces](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CinchV2_2.aspx#Service) IOpenFileService.cs to not violate the MVVM pattern.

Here is the XAML:

```
  <Button Content="Update Photo" Command="{Binding UpdatePictureCommand}"/>

  <Image Source="{Binding EmployeePicture}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Stretch="Fill" />
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
  public MainViewModel()
  {
     UpdatePictureCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnUpdatePictureCommand, CanUpdatePictureCommand);
  }

  public ICommand UpdatePictureCommand { get; private set; }
  private void OnUpdatePictureCommand(object obj)
  {
    OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
   if (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
   {
     //(listbox.SelectedItem as ContactManager.ViewModel.Contact).Photo = 
     //    LoadPhoto(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
     Stream reader = File.OpenRead(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
     System.Drawing.Image photo = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream((Stream)reader);

     MemoryStream finalStream = new MemoryStream();
     photo.Save(finalStream, ImageFormat.Png);

     // translate to image source
     PngBitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(finalStream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                                         BitmapCacheOption.Default);
     EmployeePicture =  decoder.Frames[0];;
  }

  private bool CanMoveFirstCommand(object obj)
  {
     return true;
  }

  private ImageSource _employeePicture;
  public ImageSource EmployeePicture
  {
     get
     {
        return _employeePicture;
     }
     set
     {
        _employeePicture = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("EmployeePicture");
     }
  }
```

Comment: I already tried to use a command with a command parameter (the object to update), and my code looked like yours. But I wondered the same thing about this way : Isn't the OpenFileDialog in VM breaking the pattern ? I'll give a try to Cinch to see how this problem could be handled with it.

Comment: I added a couple of links for Cinch.  There are two versions, one for VS 2008, and one for VS 2010.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I looked a bit at Cinch, and actually, it solves my problem. I'll take a look at the framework itself to implement it by myself, as a step of my "training" ;-)